sh Script Syntax Assistance
I'm trying to write a script that will read search strings from an input file and then execute a command with $string in the middle of the command line.  This is an example of the working command line:
postqueue -p | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } /typhur\.com/ { print $1 }' |  postsuper -d -

In this particular case, I'm searching my postfix queue for a string, extracting the queue id, and then piping that to the postsuper command to delete that email from the queue.  This works at the command line.
But I'd like to have a file which contains many search strings and feed that into the script. Here is a snippet of the input file I created:
/mail\.usadailyletter\.com/
/pelisplus3\.cash/
/ups\.com/
/infinitewealthtips\.com/

And here is the script:
#! /bin/sh -xv

INFILE="/usr/local/scripts/clean_mailq_infile.txt"

while read -r line; do

## echo $line for testing 
echo "$line"
        /usr/local/sbin/postqueue -p | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } "$line" { print $1 }'

done < "$INFILE"`

I removed the pipe to postsuper for testing.  At this point, assuming I have a message in my mail queue the contains "thinkapollo.com", I'd expect to see output such as:
/thinkapollo\.com/ # The current value of $line
56741273018        # The queue id returned by the command

However I only see the current value of $line and every queue id in the mail queue after each $line. Here is an example:
/thinkapollo\.com/
E190A27300F
927F027301A
CACB827301B
5CC9A273017
56741273018
5097727301D
0FCDD27301C

I should only see queue ids that match "thinkapollo.com".  I did some more reading and learned about adding "-xv' to the shebang line. I added that and ran my script:
--
+ read -r line
+ echo '/thinkapollo\.com/'
/thinkapollo\.com/
+ /usr/local/sbin/postqueue -p
+ tail -n +2
+ awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } "$line" { print $1 }'
72AD6273029
E190A27300F
927F027301A
CACB827301B
5CC9A273017
56741273018
5097727301D
0FCDD27301C
--

Thus, I suspect I don't have the right syntax for "postqueue -p" line and in particular, probably the pipe to awk part.  It seems $line is not making it to awk as a variable.  How can I fix this? I'd appreciate any nudge in the right direction.
Thanks,
Drew

"It seems $line is not making it to awk as a variable" is a correct assumption, try echo '"$line"' - you'll see that $line isn't being "expanded" - it is literally the string "$line" - that's the point of single quotes

Regarding this:
/mail\.usadailyletter\.com/
/pelisplus3\.cash/
/ups\.com/
/infinitewealthtips\.com/

You don't need to add /s and \s - just treat each line as a string instead of a regexp in the awk script.
Without seeing an example of the input to the awk command (output of postqueue -p, you don't need the | tail) and the final output you want from the awk script, this is just a guess but it might be close to what you're trying to do.
Given this in a file named input:
mail.usadailyletter.com
pelisplus3.cash
ups.com
infinitewealthtips.com

Try this, using any awk:
postqueue -p |
awk '
    NR == FNR { tgts[$0]; next }
    (FNR > 1) && !($1 in printed) {
        for ( tgt in tgts ) {
            if ( index($0,tgt) ) {
                print $1
                printed[$1]
                next
            }
        }
    }
' input - |
postsuper -d -

If that's not exactly what you need, rest assured it is at least the right starting point for what you're trying to do, you just need to update the question to provide better sample input and expected output for the awk script.
